# Oracle Where Like htmlentities

Tags: php, sql, oracle, wysiwyg, html-entities

I have a **WYSIWYG** input for a description. To save this to the database I used

```
$desc = htmlentities($_POST['desc'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
```

So on the database side, the description is saved to something like `John&amp;#39;s`. Now I want to fetch all rows where the `desc` is `LIKE` `John's`.

Before doing the query, I prepare the description:

```
$desc = strtolower(htmlentities($desc, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
```

I'm using this on my WHERE clause:

```
WHERE LOWER(desc) LIKE '%{$desc}%'
```

The query returns nothing though which is where I need your help.

**EDIT:**

On PL/SQL when I use

```
WHERE LOWER(desc) LIKE '%john&amp;#39;s%'
```

A small window appears asking about `variables` which looks something like:

```
Name    Value
=============
amp     (this part is blank)
```

Maybe this is where the problem is?

Comment: Are you sure that this doing variable replacement and is not looking for the string literal "{$desc}"?

Comment: I can surely do it the longer way by using `.` to append strings but I've done this multiple times. This is how I generally insert variables inside a string simply because of convenience and formatting.

Comment: Plus if I search for `John` it fetches the right rows as expected. The problem only comes up when there's an apostrophe in the search string.

Comment: It may then be parsing the apostraphy as the end of string, so you would need to double it up as that is the escaped single apostraphe in Oracle SQL.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton I already tried doing `WHERE LOWER(desc) LIKE '%John''s%'` and that still didn't work.

Comment: Is that a capital J in your lower(text) like....? Try lower(text) like '%john''s%'

Comment: @MichaelBroughton That was just a typo on my part. But don't worry about the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Further to our discussion in comments, and to show an example in Oracle:

```
with tab as (
           select ' xxx dave xxx' nam from dual
 union all select 'yyy Dave zzz' nam from dual
 union all select 'yyy John rrr' nam from dual
 union all select 'sss johns zzz' nam from dual
 union all select 'yyy jOHn''s zzz' nam from dual)
 select nam from tab
 where lower(nam) like '%john''s%';

NAM  
------------------            
yyy jOHn's zzz
```

So the basic construct of lower(like) '%john''s%' works in Oracle. Something in how your query is being put together seems to be the problem. Are you dumping the query string anywhere before execution so it can be tested?

Comment: Here's the query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER(desc) LIKE '%john''s%'`. I've added some information that I just found out now so please take a look at the updated post.

Comment: Instead of saving the description on the database as `John&#39;s` where `&#39;` is the HTML entity for `'`, it got saved as `John&amp;#39`. Notice the `&` got replaced by `&amp;` which is like double HTML entity encoding to me.

Comment: yes, so there's a difference between how the string gets parsed on saving, and how it's getting parsed for your query. I assume that on save you're not using the same  htmlentities($_POST['desc'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"); construct?

Comment: I'm actually using the same. Just replacing `$_POST['desc']` with `$desc`